# extract table information using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table like below, which is the filtered result from datatables. I am trying to get the whole table information in either tuple or array
e.g. [("1","abc@gmail.com"),("2","xyz@gmail.com"), ("3","pqr@gmail.com")]
and I'll have more than 2 columns and many rows.
How can this be achieved from jQuery.

```
<table id='mytable' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th id='ID'>ID</th>
        <th id='Email'>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>xyz@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>pqr@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id='gen'>Print Information</button>
```

Link to jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xLA3g/8/

Comment: I tried but was able to get only one row of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic approach to get the column data out of a table with headers as keys:

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLA3g/11/**

Based on your HTML above.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plot").click(function () {
        var headers = $.makeArray($('#mytable th').map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }));

        var data = [];
        $('#mytable tr').each(function(cRowIndex, cRow) {
            var cRowData = {};

            $(cRow).find('td').each(function(cIndex, cTD) {
                cRowData[headers[cIndex]] = $(cTD).text();
            });

            if ($(cRow).find('td').length) {
                data.push(cRowData);
            }
        });

        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

This could be converted in to a plugin:

```
$.fn.getTableData = function() {
    var headers = $.makeArray($(this).find('th').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }));

    var data = [];
    $(this).find('tr').each(function(cRowIndex, cRow) {
        var cRowData = {};

        $(cRow).find('td').each(function(cIndex, cTD) {
            cRowData[headers[cIndex]] = $(cTD).text();
        });

        if ($(cRow).find('td').length) {
            data.push(cRowData);
        }
    });

    return data;    
};
```

Called as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plot").click(function () {
        var data = $('#mytable').getTableData();
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle (plugin): http://jsfiddle.net/xLA3g/16/**

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = $('#mytable tr:gt(0)').map(function () {
    return $(this).find('td').map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
}).get();
```

Comment: Why help him, he put in 0 effort?

Comment: instead of `$(this).text();` you can use `this.textContent`

Comment: I tried but was able to get only one row information...
$('#mytable tr td:first-child').each(function(i){
    alert($(this).text());
});

Comment: @TusharGupta - That doesn't work in IE, which uses `nodeValue`, so I'm using jQuery to normalize.

Comment: @JosephSilber, thanks for possible solution, but I get empty data

Answer (score 1):

If your table structure is fixed then,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tuple = [];
    $('#mytable tr:gt(0)').each(function(i) {
       $('td', this).each(function() {
          tuple[i] = $(this).text();
       });
    });
    console.log(tuple);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xLA3g/10/)

Comment: thanks, but the table structure is not fixed :(
on filtering the column and row number might vary..

Comment: @user1051068 check the update solution